# Matches decorator of class-validator does not work correctly

Tags: typescript, nestjs, class-validator

I'm learning nestjs as my job requirement

here is my regex: `/(?=[^\d].*)^[\w]{4,}$/` which means the first character must not be a number, at least 4 characters for the whole string

here the DTO:

```js
import { IsString, IsPhoneNumber, Matches } from 'class-validator';
export class CreateUserDto {
  @Matches(/(?=[^\d].*)^[\w]{4,}$/, {
    message:
      'the first character of the username must not be a number. Username must contains at least 4 characters',
  })
  username: string;

  @IsString()
  password: string;

  @IsPhoneNumber('VN')
  phoneNumber: string;
}
```

whatever the username in the request body is, it still passed, even an empty string
but when I post a plain number for the username field, the server responded an error as default action of the Matches decorator

```json
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "message": [
        "username must be a string"
    ],
    "error": "Bad Request"
}
```

I have also enabled Validation in main.ts

```js
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors();
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  await app.listen(9000);
}
bootstrap();
```

could anyone explain for me? thanks for your help

Comment: Do you mean at least four characters instead of words?

Comment: Also, not only a matched string must not be a number. It must not start with a number as well, for example `333jjj` will not be matched.

Comment: and what exactly was the problem?

Comment: previously, I couldn't validate the username field by regex using Matches decorator.
but after deleting `dist` folder. It works like a charm.
actually, I've just fixed my problem. Anyway, thanks for your attention :)

Comment: oh yeah, I meant 'characters'. That's my misspellings

Comment: if it solved your problem, please accept your own answer so that everybody knows that your question doesn't need any more care

Answer (score 0, accepted):

weirdly, I've resolved this problem by deleting `dist` folder

maybe ts transpiler did not re-transpile the newest ts code to js code. I have no reason why